# Trying to set a variable based on multiple if-elseif conditions in PHP

Tags: php

I'm working with an event calendar in PHP.  The calendar itself works perfectly, but I'm trying to color-code individual entries in the calendar based on event start/end times.  I have if/elseif logic that works using only start time, but my attempt to use start **and** end times has resulted in strangeness.

Here is the function:

```
function get_bg_color ($event_start) {

    // set colors for shifts
    // 0 = grave
    // 1 = days
    // 2 = swing
    // 3 = weekend
    // 4 = day-swing
    // 5 = grave-day
    // 6 = swing-grave

    // $hr = date('H', $event_start);
    $hr = date('H:i', $event_start);
    $hour1 = str_replace(':', '', $hr);
    $hr2 = date('H:i', $event_end);
    $hour2 = str_replace(':', '', $hr2);
    $day = date('L', $event_start);
    if ($day == "sunday" || $day == "saturday") {$color="3";}
#       elseif ($hour1 > 0 && $hour1 < 730) {$color="0";}
#       elseif ($hour1 >= 730 && $hour1 < 1300) {$color="1";}
#       elseif ($hour1 >= 1300 && $hour1 < 1530) {$color="4";}
#       elseif ($hour1 >= 1530 && $hour1 < 2100) {$color="2";}
#       else {$color="0";}
    else {
            if ($hour1 > 0 && $hour1 < 730) {
                    if ($hour2 < 730) {$color="0";}
                    elseif ($hour2 >= 730 && $hour2 < 1300) {$color="5";}
            }
            elseif ($hour1 >= 730 && $hour1 < 1300) {
                    if ($hour2 <= 1300) {$color="1";}
                    elseif ($hour2 >= 1300 && $hour2 < 1530) {$color="4";}
            }
            elseif ($hour1 >= 1300 && $hour1 < 1530) {
                    if ($hour2 <= 1530) {$color="4";}
                    elseif ($hour2 >= 1530 && $hour2 < 2100) {$color="4";}
            }
            elseif ($hour1 >= 1530 && $hour1 < 2100) {
                    if ($hour2 <= 2100) {$color="2";}
                    elseif ($hour2 > 2100) {$color="6";}
            }
            else {$color="0";}
    }
    return $color;
}
```

The commented-out elseifs are the functioning version of the logic which only uses the start time.  The lower block of elseifs (my modified start/end logic) keeps giving me errant weekend coloring for events which don't fall on a weekend.

Colors are defined in a separate `style.css`.  The `$event_start` and `$event_end` variables are pulled from a database.  These all work, as tested in the commented block.

Comment: So exactly what ___strangeness___ are you seeeing?

Comment: `date('L', $event_start);` returns a number not a day name string! `date('l', $event_start);` returns a day name SO that woudl cause ___strangeness___ to your code

Comment: Good job, detective Folly.

Comment: @Farkie I think you mean Defective Folly :)

Comment: Put $color="0"; out side the if statements. Up by where you have the other variables defined. You may have a scope problem where the variable is created then destroyed with in the if statement. Thus has no value when you return it. Also do you set $event_end any where?

Comment: Your second elseif, this one `elseif ($hour1 >= 1300 && $hour1 < 1530) {
                    if ($hour2 <= 1530) {$color="4";}
                    elseif ($hour2 >= 1530 && $hour2 < 2100) {$color="4";}` returns **4** in both cases. Could that be an error, beg pardon ___a strangeness___?

Comment: Your function has only one parameter `get_bg_color ($event_start)` but you use a variable called `$event_end` inside the function??? **Where does that come from?** Is that another ___strangemess___

Comment: So many **strangeness** going on

Comment: RiggsFolly: The _**strangeness**_ I'm seeing is that the weekend color is showing for weekday events.  The `date('L', $event_start);` bit of code existed before I got my hands on it, and it seems to perform correctly regardless of improper usage.  I'll try the lowercase and see if it makes a difference.

As for the second elseif returning **4** in both cases, it's actually doing what I want it to, and allows for a degree of granularity should timings change in the future.

Comment: Can someone offer up examples of how I might perform the function I'm trying to perform - that of using PHP to set a background color, defined in style.css, based upon two variables, $event_start and $event_end.  Please illustrate my missteps, and pardon my usage of actual English in my explanations.

Comment: I have done my best, see answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I have caught all the ***strangeness***

```
function get_bg_color ($event_start, $event_end) {
//    --------- Missing Parameter ---^^^^^^^^^^ 
// needs this parameter on function call as well

    $hour1 = date('Hi', $event_start);
    // use the format required, save an instruction
    //$hour1 = str_replace(':', '', $hr);

    $hour2 = date('Hi', $event_end);

    // will NOT return a day name, will return 0,1,2,3,4,5,6
    //$day = date('L', $event_start);

    // will return a day name but need converting to lower case
    // so it matches your IF tests which are in lower case
    $day = strtolower(date('l', $event_start));

    // always a good idea to init returned values
    $color = "0";


    if ($day == "sunday" || $day == "saturday") 
    {
        $color="3";
    } else {
            if ($hour1 > 0 && $hour1 < 730) {
                if ($hour2 < 730) {$color="0";}
                elseif ($hour2 >= 730 && $hour2 < 1300) {$color="5";}
            }
            elseif ($hour1 >= 730 && $hour1 < 1300) {
                if ($hour2 <= 1300) {$color="1";}
                elseif ($hour2 >= 1300 && $hour2 < 1530) {$color="4";}
            }
            elseif ($hour1 >= 1300 && $hour1 < 1530) {
                if ($hour2 <= 1530) {$color="4";}
                elseif ($hour2 >= 1530 && $hour2 < 2100) {$color="4";}
            }
            elseif ($hour1 >= 1530 && $hour1 < 2100) {
                if ($hour2 <= 2100) {$color="2";}
                elseif ($hour2 > 2100) {$color="6";}
            }
            else {$color="0";}
    }
    return $color;
}
```

> Dont forget to check that the call to this function has 2 relevant parameters now as well

Comment: Thank you, RiggsFolly.  I'll make those changes and comment here with my result.

Comment: RiggsFolly:  I have made your suggested changes to this function, but I'm still seeing the same incorrect output.  Plus, if I add $event_end to the function get_bg_color, I get "Warning: Missing argument 2 for get_bg_color()"

Comment: See the yellow bit at the bottom of my answer. If you dont see it refresh the page

Comment: Yep, I see that now, but I honestly don't know what to do with it.  As I mentioned near the top of my post, I'm no kind of programmer to speak of -- total noob.  Working with pre-existing code.  Suggestions?

Comment: Think I got it.  Will inform when I have a result.

Comment: RiggsFolly, I love you!  Thank you SO much for your help!

Comment: Haha :) And for future refrerence when developers talk about these  ___strangnesses__ they call them **bugs**

Comment: Hm.  Have found another, er, bug.  The calendar now renders with all desired colors except for events starting at 0730, which are rendering with color 0, where they should be color 5.  Did I miss something?

Comment: HA!  Fixed!  I had slightly-incorrect operators in my event time checks.